# Show resize handle on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I need elements to be resizable using resize: both, and it does work, but I want to show the corner handle just when hovering the element, is there a way to do it?

[image]

That's the handle I want to show on hover only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `resize: both;` inside the `:hover` rule

```css
.resize {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.resize:hover {
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize"></div>
```

Comment: That was smart jaja, thanks!